# Ember.set and Ember.setProperties gives different results

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-observable

I ran into a problem in my `Ember` application where setting multiple properties using `Ember.set` and `Ember.setProperties` produced a buggy result in the latter. Constructed an exact scenario here.

**HBS**:

```
Name: {{name}}<br>
Place: {{place}}<br><br>

<button {{action "modifyTogether"}}>this.setProperties({name:"Vignesh Raja",place:"Namakkal"})</button>

<br><br><br>

<button {{action "modifySeperately"}}>this.set("name","Vignesh Raja");<br>this.set("place","Namakkal");</button>

<br><br><br>

When set seperately, we get the latest value - {name:"Vignesh Raja", place:"Namakkal"}<br>
When set together, we get the latest value from the observer- {name:"Vignesh Raja", place:"Chennai"}<br>
<br>
<br>
```

**JS**:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    name:"Vignesh",
    place:"Nmkl",

    handleName1 : function(){
        this.set("place","Chennai");
    }.observes("name"),

    actions:{
        modifyTogether:function(){
            this.setProperties({name:"Vignesh Raja",place:"Namakkal"})
        },

        modifySeperately:function(){
            this.set("name","Vignesh Raja");
            this.set("place","Namakkal");
        }
    }
});
```

[Ember Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/8eb228601ea30187ed0b9a2b703524ff?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C)

In the above code, clicking first button (`Ember.setProperties`) gives `Name: Vignesh Raja Place: Chennai`, but clicking second (multiple `Ember.set`) gives `Name: Vignesh Raja Place: Namakkal`

Comment: sidenote: you should never use observers to set embers own state.

Answer (score 2):

The problem I ran into was due to the `Ember Observer` assigned to the `name` property.

While updating separately, first `this.set("name","Vignesh Raja")` sets the value of `name` property. Then its observer is fired and `place` property gets changed to `Chennai`. After these, second statement, `this.set("place","Namakkal")` is fired. So we get `Namakkal` as the final value.

Hence the result - `Name: Vignesh Raja Place: Namakkal`

While updating together, `Ember.setProperties` buffers the observers until all the properties passed are updated. It groups the property changes using `Ember.beginPropertyChanges`, and the value changed notifications are not sent to the observers. Once the properties are set, `Ember.endPropertyChanges` is called which in turn sends the notifications to the observers. So in the above example, `this.setProperties({name:"Vignesh Raja",place:"Namakkal"})`, sets the properties `name` and `place` and after finishing, the observer changes the property `place` to `Chennai`.

Hence the result - `Name: Vignesh Raja Place: Chennai`.

So if using the `Ember.setProperties`, Make sure any observer of any properties you set, won't change the value of other properties.